# Looking for a practical book on IR spectroscopy techniques (LIF, TLDAS, FTIR, etc)

Tags: ir-spectroscopy, raman

I am looking for a book that would ideally delve into the more practical and applied side of the IR spectroscopic techniques. Anyone can recommend me a a good book about this topic?

I have somewhat of a background in quantum mechanics and optics side of things, I am more interested in the actual implementation of these techniques.

As for the abbreviations used above:

- LIF: [Laser-induced fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-induced_fluorescence)
- TLDAS: [Tunable diode laser absorption spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunable_diode_laser_absorption_spectroscopy)
- FT-IR: [Fourier-transform infrared spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-transform_infrared_spectroscopy)

Comment: Though it isn't a substitute for a literature search/visit of a research library, the entries in Wikipedia added to translate the acronyms can be one entry.  Well, perhaps with the exception of FT (hard to find a modern IR spectrometer which doesn't use it, even old editions of the Silverstein book ([resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)) cover it).